# Problems installing python-nltk

Tags: python

I've tried the following :
1)

```
   sudo apt-get install python-nltk
   sudo apt-get install python-tk
   sudo apt-get install python-numpy
   sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

The last 3 are just to avoid dependancy problems later.

2) I've also tried to build nltk from source.

None of the two approaches over work. This is the error I get:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov  1 2011, 23:57:57) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)
2. `sudo easy_install pip`
3. `sudo pip install -U numpy`
4. `sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk`
5. run `python` then type `import nltk`

Comment: This is the ight answer! Thanks! @Arnab Datta check this answer as the right one!